# ipptool client-error-document-format-not-supported

Tags: linux, cups, ipp

The command line command:

```
ipptool http://192.168.1.102:631 print_pdf
```

The contents of print_pdf:

```
{
    VERSION 2.0
    OPERATION Print-Job
    REQUEST-ID 5

    GROUP operation-attributes-tag
    ATTR charset "attributes-charset" "utf-8"
    ATTR naturalLanguage "attributes-natural-language" "en"
    ATTR uri "printer-uri" "http://192.168.1.102:631"
    ATTR name "requesting-user-name" "John"
    ATTR mimeMediaType "document-format" "application/pdf"

    FILE "steampunk.pdf"
}
```

EDIT: Now I have the error `client-error-document-format-not-supported`, even though this is the standard application/pdf format.

The docs in the [repository](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups) do not discuss this error too thoroughly.
The image below appears to be where the issue is raised, something to do with a ppd file?
[image]
What could be the issue?

Comment: Since you're not giving a full path to print_pdf, does ipp_tool automatically know where to find it and does have proper permission to access the file?

Comment: Not quite, the issue was with the printer uri. Now however I have a different error

Comment: Is it a printer on the other side, or is it a CUPS print server? I'm not entirely sure if the `printer-uri` `http://192.168.1.102:631` is entirely valid, I think it needs to actually target a destination (under `/printers/` or `/classes/`). You can get the default via a `Cups-Get-Default` operation if it's a cups server. If you're directly sending to a printer, you might want to check the printer's `document-format-supported` attribute from a `Get-Printer-Supported-Values` operation.

Comment: Get-Printer-Supported-Values is not a supported server operation, a `Get-Printer-Attributes` fails with the same error:
`{
    OPERATION Get-Printer-Attributes

    GROUP operation-attributes-tag
    ATTR charset "attributes-charset" "utf-8"
    ATTR naturalLanguage "attributes-natural-language" "en"
    ATTR uri "printer-uri" "http://192.168.1.102:631"
    ATTR name "requesting-user-name" "John Doe"
    ATTR mimeMediaType "document-format" "application/pdf"
    ATTR keyword "requested-attributes" "printer-description","job-template","media-col-database"
}`

Comment: Could you try the same `Get-Printer-Attributes` operation, but remove `ATTR mimeMediaType "document-format" "application/pdf"` and add `document-format-supported` to the `requested-attributes` list?

Comment: It is successful, as the only supported format I get `application/vnd.brother-hbp`. I guess that explains it